# Handling DOM Events like "transitionend" with "async ... await" - will this work?

Tags: javascript, async-await, dom-events

I am doing a lot of stuff where I have to react to CSS transitions and animations. It is always a hassle to do all the setup, as defining handlers (which often have to be bound as well).

Now, as I slowly transition to ES8 I have found something that seems to actually work, and will drastically reduce my boilerplate.

So, the question is, will this have no weird side effects I may have overlooked?

```
let resFunc;

await new Promise(resolve => {
    resFunc = resolve;
    myEle.addEventListener("transitionend", resFunc);
    myEle.classList.add("animate");
});

myEle.removeEventListener("transitionend", resFunc);

// continue doing stuff
```

Almost looks to good to be true ;)

In theory, I could write this even shorter:

```
await new Promise(resolve => {
    myEle.addEventListener("transitionend", resolve);
    myEle.classList.add("animate");
});

// continue doing stuff
```

I mean, even if there is another transition on the same element, the `resolve` function would be called again, but should do nothing, as Promises only can resolve once, right?

And it also would introduce a (small?) memory leak, right?

Comment: how about `myEle.addEventListener('transitionend', resolve, { once: true })`?

Comment: Yeah, good idea, but `{ once: true }`AFAIK only works in relatively recent browsers.